# How to setup and run openpaas release version in ubuntu

Tags: angularjs, docker-compose

I am trying to setup openpaas: [https://github.com/linagora/openpaas-esn ] development on ubuntu system. i am unable to setup.

before seting up locally , i tried running with docker(as in http://docs.open-paas.org/getting-started/linux/ ) it works fine.i need to setup locally (as in https://github.com/linagora/openpaas-esn/blob/master/doc/develop.md), i am facing problem.

now I am following developer documentation: https://github.com/linagora/openpaas-esn/blob/master/doc/develop.md ,after setup installation is complete and point browser to http://localhost:8080 , i get login page But after logging as admin(admin@open-paas.org), i am getting blank screen. I can see error in chrome console.How can i setup locally and run openpaas .

In documentation it says front end is vue.js , but i am getting Angular js, ng route related error .

installed angular router but this did not help .

as in https://github.com/linagora/openpaas-esn/blob/master/docker/doc/known_issues.md , i tried

```
    docker exec esn_james java -jar /root/james-cli.jar -h localhost adddomain open-paas.org
```

I did checkout openpass : https://github.com/linagora/openpaas-esn to home folder.

then did

```
npm install
```

to run dependecy software as in documentation, i run docker-compose up as below. so redis,rabbitmq,mongo,elasticsearch,sabre,james,james_elastic,cassandra are running in docker,then tested , i am able to connect.

```
    ESN_HOST="172.17.0.1" ESN_PATH="$PWD" docker-compose -f ./docker/dockerfiles/dev/docker-compose.yml up
```

then as per documentation , to run openpaas with below command

```
    grunt dev
```

tried alternative ways

```
    node ./bin/cli.js
```

openpaas is up and running, on pointing browser to http://localhost:8080/ , i get login page , after login i get blank screen. and error in chrome console

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/modulerr?

how do i get it running.

need to setup openpaas locally for start development/customise to my needs.

since i cannot create tag, and openpaas tag is not already present, just added angularjs tag

Comment: i can see bower.json , i understand i need to execute bower install. documentation is not complete i think but still it does not work.

Comment: "In documentation it says frontend is vue.js" Can you tell me which document? For your information, OpenPaaS frontend has been developing using Angularjs. The OpenPaaS team are moving to Vuejs for new modules but do not have plan refactor exist modules or platform core in Angularjs to Vue. For the error, I followed your reproduce steps and it works.
Can you try to remove `node-modules` and `frontend/components` and run `npm install` and `bower install` again?

Comment: @TuanLECONG thanks for your response.  as you said i have tried this many times ,  removing `node-modules` and `frontend/components` ,then `npm i` and `bower install` . it worked for you can you can you please point me the right openpaas version and OS that worked for you.